# Session PHP for Different Web Browsers

Tags: php, html, forms, session, browser

I just created a form with a php script using a `session`.

For example if I fill out the form and then in the process and the results show up in Google Chrome.

At the same time, can I see the results also in other web browsers like Mozilla?

Comment: try reading more on sessions.

Comment: No, cookies are not global across browsers.

Comment: Sessions, by their very nature, are per-browser.

Comment: I would say `cookies`, since `sessions` are managed by the server -- and sessions can also exist not as a cookie, but as a get variable.

Answer (score 3):

**No.**  Each different browser keeps its own set of cookies (which are the technology underlying sessions) - they are not shared between different browsers.